# Merge C# DLL's into .EXE

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, merge, fluent

I know there are many reply to this topic, but the example code which I found on this replys dont work for each .dll

I used [this](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/05/14/wpf-how-to-combine-mutliple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe/) example.

```
public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(ResolveAssembly);
    }

    static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        //We dont' care about System Assemblies and so on...
        if (!args.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("wpfcontrol")) return null;

        Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //Get the Name of the AssemblyFile
        var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";

        //Load form Embedded Resources - This Function is not called if the Assembly is in the Application Folder
        var resources = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(s => s.EndsWith(name));
        if (resources.Count() > 0)
        {
            var resourceName = resources.First();
            using (Stream stream = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                if (stream == null) return null;
                var block = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(block);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When i created a little program with only one window and a butten it had works, but with my "big" dll it hadnt work. The settings on the "big" dll are the same like that from my little programm.

I cant imagine why it does work sometimes and sometimes it doesnt work. I tested it with the ICSharp.AvalonEdit.dll too, unsuccessful..

can anyone imagine where the error is?

## Edit 1

When i start my program it says that it cant found my dll.

## Edit 2

I think i got the core of my issue. If one of the dll's, that i want to merge contains a reference to an other dll, than i become this `FileNotFoundException` exception. Do somebody know how to load/add also the internal required dll's

## Edit 3

When i using the Code from Jiří Polášek it works for some. My [Fluent](http://fluent.codeplex.com/releases) shows the error "Please, attach a ResourceDictionary with styles. But i had done this already in my `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2010/Silver.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your referenced assembly requires other assemblies, you have to include them with your application as well - either in application folder or as embedded resource. You can determine referenced assemblies using Visual Studio, IL Spy, dotPeek, or write you own tool using method [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx).

It's also possible that `AssemblyResolve` event is fired before you attach `ResolveAssembly` handler to it. Attaching handler should be the first thing you do in your Main method. In WPF you have to create new class with new Main method a set it as *Startup object* in project settings.

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThreadAttribute]
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve
            += new ResolveEventHandler(ResolveAssembly);
        WpfApplication1.App app = new WpfApplication1.App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }

    public static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {   
      // check condition on the top of your original implementation
    }
}
```

You should also check guard condition on the top of `ResolveAssembly` to not exclude any referenced assembly.

Comment: After using your code, i get some trouble. pls show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328483/problems-after-merging-fluent-into-main-exe)